# How can I put my html / php text-json output in a variable?

Tags: php, html, json

I want to write a script for an api from a website. This website gives you the data in a text that is like a json text.

```
[ { "nickname":"dieeeeeeter", "votes":"9"   },  { "nickname":"Honk", "votes":"9"    },
```

I just want to add the nickname and the number of votes into my database, so I delete (replace) everything else.

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = str_replace('"', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(':', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('{}', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('nickname', '', $data);
$data = str_replace('votes', '', $data);
```

So now my text output looks like this

```
{ Honk, 9   },  { dieeeeeeter, 9    }
```

But I don't know how I can but my data into a variable like "$username".
Can you help me ?

Comment: instead of str_replace use json_decode function to convert json string to array/object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use json_decode php function to convert json string to array and loop the array to get the values and insert them to database.

```
$json_string = '[ { "nickname":"dieeeeeeter", "votes":"9"},  { "nickname":"Honk", "votes":"9"}]';

$data_array = json_decode($json_string ,true);
print_r($data_array );

foreach($data_array as $data){
    $nickname = trim($data['nickname']);
    $votes = trim($data['votes']);
    // insert query goes here
}
```

Out put of array will be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nickname] => dieeeeeeter
            [votes] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nickname] => Honk
            [votes] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: But how can I enter the array to mysql ? It doesn't work if I do it like: